# How to write NON ASCII data in one file with php

Tags: php, binary-data

I must write a binary file with php, but I think that I don't use the correct method.

I use this function:

```
$ptr = fopen("file.txt", 'wb');
fwrite($ptr, $Str);
fclose($ptr);
```

I write this string (chaotic representation of 0 and 1):

```
$Str="00000001001110000000000100000100000000000000001000000010000000010000001100000101000000000000010000000001000000000000010100000";
```

I thought that opening the file with OpenOffice I would not have seen the text of zeros and ones, but instead I was sure I saw a chaotic sequence of characters.
Why I see the zeros and ones in open office? How can I do to write the raw data with php?

Comment: It seems to work for me... Perhaps it is an issue with your OpenOffice... have you tried it with http://www.libreoffice.org/?

Answer (score 1):

If you write text in a file, even when open in binary mode, you will get text in the file. Your `0` is not stored as a zero bit, but as the ASCII representation of the `0` caracter.

Use the binary format for numbers in PHP, for instance:

```
$var = OxFF; // equals to 1111 1111 in binary.
```

[More in the manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can write any character with the [`chr()`](http://php.net/chr) function.

Alternatively, you can do something like `"\x0A"` (that's a newline character).

Comment: thanks, but i want write a raw file, non ascii file. I would like write some data each one of 8 bit, surely i must write all data without separator, knowing the length of the data that is constant 8-bit I can read any data.
That way I can write and retrieve a lot of data by reducing the space in the file than to write it in ascii.